# Non-suffix wildcard in CSP

Tags: javascript, html, content-security-policy

I'm building an app that allows users to execute code in a sandboxed iframe (think jsbin/etc), but this project has the particular constraint that user code should *ideally* be immutable.

I could:

- specify a CSP that doesn't allow them to import any scripts, but that would be very sub-optimal
- generate an integrity hash for imported scripts when they submit code and then add that, but that has some significant downsides given the particular constraints of this project (please trust me here)
- serve code only from the site's own domain, but again this has significant down-sides given the constraints of the project

The ideal approach for my particular case would be to **restrict users to importing from a set of known-immutable CDN sources** like `jsdelivr`. The problem is that these sources are only immutable if they have the version in the URL.

So, for example:

- **immutable**: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/marked@4.2.12/marked.min.js
- **mutable**: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/marked/marked.min.js

(it's possible for a package to be taken down from NPM, but IIUC this only happens in rare circumstances, like if there is copyright violation)

I'm wondering whether there's any sort of browser mechanism (my first thought was CSP, hence title) that could allow me to enforce that imported scripts are:

1. from specific domains, and
2. have the full version in their URL

IIUC, CSP only allows specifying prefixes by including the trailing slash like `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/`. It doesn't allow me to do something like `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/marked@*.*.*/`, or even better `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/marked@[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+/`.

I'm not really expecting that there's a solution here, but figured I'd ask in case at least one spec author happens to read this and maybe considers a more granular wild-carding system for a future version of the spec. But maybe there is some sort of creative solution here that I haven't thought of.

Comment: Really *every* external script is mutable. What you're really looking for is not a `nonce` but rather [an `integrity` hash](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity)

Comment: Thanks, fixed the question RE nonce vs integrity hash. As mentioned this approach isn't really appropriate given the constraints of the project. I was weary about giving any context for this reason (hence the "please trust me on this") because I'm trying to avoid explaining the whole, essay-long context. What I'm really just looking for here is the ability to specify wildcards within CSP URLs. As I mentioned in the last paragraph, I don't really expect a satisfying answer here.

Comment: What are the constraints of the project and what are its goals? What exactly does "immutable code" mean to you? And more importantly, how are your users adding scripts to their pages?

Comment: No, CSP does not allow wildcard or pattern matching. Subresource integrity is what you really want here. And I doubt spec authors will go browsing StackOverflow for input, you should rather [open an issue](https://github.com/w3c/webappsec-csp/issues) on the spec.